# Upper semicontinuous decomposition

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm reading a paper from Y. Ünlü called *Lattices of compactifications of Tychonoff spaces*. I've bumped into some definitions that I've never seen; while I find most of them understandable, there's one that I can't break down.

**Definition 1.** A decomposition $\alpha$ of a space $X$ is a partition of $X$ into compact sets.

So far, this one is easy to understand.

**Definition 2.** A decomposition $\alpha$ of a set $X$ is called upper semicontinuous if for $K \in \alpha$, $K \subset V$ and $V$ is open in $X$, then there is an open set $W$ in $X$ such that $K \subset W \subset V$ and $W = \bigcup \{L \in \alpha\ \textrm{s.t.}\ L \cap W \neq \emptyset\}$. A set $W$ satisfying this condition is called $\alpha$-saturated.

It's here where I come into trouble. In $W = \bigcup \{L \in \alpha\ \textrm{s.t.}\ W \cap L \neq \emptyset\}$ how can we express $W$ in terms of itself, if it hasn't already been defined?

Could you please clarify this definition (maybe it's a typo and the author wanted to write $V$ instead of $W$, or maybe I'm not good enough to get it) and give me some equivalent statement?

Comment: $W$ isn't being defined by the equation, rather it is only a condition that must hold. $W$ is some open set $K\subseteq W\subseteq V$, so you can find one (you can always take $W=V$), calculate the right-hand side and see what you get.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! Could you give me an example of an upper semicontinuous decomposition?

Comment: The survey paper linked in my answer gives some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better formulation of the notion of upper semicontinuous decompositions is to demand

> If $V \subseteq X$ is open, then $W= \bigcup \{K: K \in \alpha: K \subseteq V\}$ is open in $X$ and this is equivalent to the quotient map $q$ (defined by the decomposition onto the set of classes $X{/}\alpha$ being an open map.

See [this survey](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/2064-02.pdf) for more explanation.

Then if $\alpha$ satisfies this and we have (as in your situation) $K \in \alpha, K \subseteq V$, we take $W$ as promised, which is open (and clearly contains $\alpha$) and if $L \in \alpha$ intersects $W$, then $L \subseteq W$ (because we have a partition: some $x \in L$ is contained in an $L'$ that sits inside $W$ (by definition of $W$) but $L=L'$ as intersecting means equality in a partition.), and $W$ is saturated.

And *no*, the definition as stated is just the *definition of being saturated* not the definition of $W$ itself. A set $S$ (in general) is saturated for a partition $\alpha$, iff $$\forall K \in \alpha: (K \cap S \neq \emptyset) \to K \subseteq S$$

(so if you have a point of a member you have the whole member;  " if you eat them a bit, you eat them completely", to put it weirdly.)

Comment: I appreciate it so much!

Comment: @Roger You're welcome. It's a classic topic.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hi Henno, doesn't the condition for upper semicontinous decompositions correspond to a closed quotient map, instead of an open one?

Comment: @PatrickR No, see 3.1c in the linked paper.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't see a 3.1c in the paper.  Did you mean Definition 3.3(1) instead?